# How to stop thread returning before Join() is called

Tags: java, multithreading

This is purely a theoretical question as I'm not sure the conditions to cause this issue would be common.

Say for example you have a thread that you kick off with it's start method:

```
Thread c = new Thread();
c.start();
```

Then directly after, you call the Join() method on the thread to tell the method you are in to wait until the thread had been executed to continue.

```
c.join();
```

Isn't it a possibility that the thread could possibly be executed and finish before the join method is called, therefore leaving the method unaware that it had to wait for c to finish before it continued? I suppose you could try calling the join() method before you call the start() method, yet whenever I've tried this in test cases, there is an error.

Anyone know a possible fix for this, or does the JVM handle it? As I said I haven't been able to trigger this sort of situation, but theoretically it is possible...

Comment: With the answers that others have opined, it won't be wrong to conclude that join() on any other Thread, is just a check of criteria, for the calling Thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the `Thread#join(long millis)` source code, the `isAlive()` method is used to check the thread state.

```
/**
 * Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has
 * been started and has not yet died.
 *
 * @return  <code>true</code> if this thread is alive;
 *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
 */
public final native boolean isAlive();
```

This method obviously returns `false` if the thread has finished, so `thread.join()` will immediately exit.

Answer (score 8):

`c.join()` means that the currently executing thread should wait for `c` to complete before finishing.  If `c` executes completely before the call to `c.join()` is made, then that condition is satisfied, as `c` has completed execution.  The method in which you're calling `c.join()` wouldn't "know about it"; `c.join()` would just be like a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `join()` before a Thread is started, but because the Thread hasn't been started `join()` will return immediately.

If `join()` is called after the Thread is started, and the Thread has terminated, `join()` will also return immediately.

The only time `join()` will block is while the `Thread.isAlive()`

This code works OK...

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
   {
      Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable()
      { 
         public void run()
         {
            System.out.println( "thread" );
         }
      } );
      t.join();
      System.out.println( "joined" );

      Thread.sleep( 2000 );
      System.out.println( "call start" );
      t.start(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The join method semantics mean "to wait until the joining thread is finished", and that is pretty much the standard in every programming language that supports multi-threading. Therefore, it is perfectly possible to join an already finished thread, the JVM will simply detect that it has already finished and proceed with the code execution.

Answer (score 0):

join() will return immediately if the thread is not running.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use CountdownLatch with callable and future. For example, http://sycure.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/example-using-java-future-and-countdownlatch/